# Array Transpose: Error reading property from "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, transpose

Getting an error message for the below code that works to get Values from several cells in my order entry tab named POTemplate and log them in my POHistory tab the serves to compile a list of all order detail entries. As the debugger gets to the bottom of the below code, I get an error message stating: "Cannot Read Property 0.0 from Undefined"

```
function submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var tplSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var tplFRow = 22, tplLRow = tplSheet.getLastRow();
  var tplRowsNum = tplLRow - tplFRow + 1;
  var tplFCol = 1, tplLCol = 16;
  var tplColsNum = tplLCol - tplFCol + 1;
  var rangeData = tplSheet.getRange(22, 1, 5, 15).getValues();
  var colIndexes = [0, 3, 10, 12, 15];
  var fData = filterByIndexes(rangeData, colIndexes);
  var target = "POHistory";
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(target);
  var tgtRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var tgtRowsNum = fData.length - tgtRow + 1;
  var tgtCol = 1;
  var tgtColsNum = fData[0].length - 1 + 1;
  targetSheet.getRange(tgtRow, tgtCol, tgtRowsNum, 
  tgtColsNum).setValues(fData);
}

function filterByIndexes(twoDArr, indexArr) {
  var fData = [];
  twoDArr = twoDArr.transpose();
  for(var i = 0; i < indexArr.length; i++) {
     fData.push(twoDArr[indexArr[i]]);
  }
  return fData.transpose();
}

Array.prototype.transpose = function() {
  var a = this,
      w = a.length ? a.length : 0,
      h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;
  if (h === 0 || w === 0) {return [];}
  var i, j, t = [];
  for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
     t[i] = [];
     for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
       t[i][j] = a[j][i];
     }
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: You should add the specific line number at which you have an issue. Editing your code to remove your actual data read, preferring instead to call your method on some test cases, will help everyone as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tehhowch.  The specific line that is causing the issue is:    t[i][j] = a[j][i];  the fifth from the bottom.  I am new to this, somewhat, so wasn't fully clear on your additional suggestion, unfortunately.  Either way, thank you for your help.

Comment: Essentially, you are calling `transpose()` on an array that we have no idea about. If you instead construct simple test arrays, e.g. stuff like `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]`, `[["r1"],["r2"]]`, and `[["c1", "c2"]]` and then call `transpose()` on them, figuring out where the error is much simpler.

Comment: As for this specific error, it occurs whenever `a[j]` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, tehhowch.  I should've been more clear with my original post.  I am constructing the array from line 22 to 36 in the POTemplate tab.  This allows for us to enter item details line by line for an order request that comes through for a customer.  I am looking to then grab each line item's details to transpose to the POHistory tab to serve as a running log of all orders that have been placed through the POTemplate tab.  Hoping this helps answer your question.

Comment: No, it was clear enough in your original post. I'm saying that you should use some unit tests to prove to yourself that `transpose()` is working as intended (your error indicates it is not). To reduce the complexity when diagnosing the problem, you want to start with simple, easily verifiable inputs - such as a square array, row array, and column array.

Comment: tehhowch - I created a sample Google Sheet file to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, I am still a bit unclear on how to move forward.  The example sheet is found via the following link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165aQCNdDdTJtmVOIs2Jn7KbCMxhHN4YF1a22ExenlGo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Essentially the code would grab all elements from the POTemplate that are listed in row 1 of the POHistory tab and list them for future reference.  Thanks so much.

Comment: write a "feeder function" in your Apps Script project: `function testTranspose() { var a = [["c1", "c2"]]; Logger.log(a); Logger.log(a.transpose()); }` Set a breakpoint (click the line number) on the first line in your transpose function, and use the bug icon to enter debug mode. Use "step into" to advance line by line, and check your function's logic. If `transpose()` works for every test case, then the error is elsewhere.

Comment: That might be a little advanced for someone as new to this as I am, unfortunately.  Were you able to pull up my sample project via the link provided?  Hoping you might have some alternative suggestions after viewing the sample project.