# Get/Set Values from One Tab to Another using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Getting the following error message [TypeError: Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined. (line 39, file "Code")] when trying to execute a get/setValue range from one tab (POTemplate) to another (POHistory) in the Google Sheet file found via the following link:   [Please follow this link to POTemplate Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165aQCNdDdTJtmVOIs2Jn7KbCMxhHN4YF1a22ExenlGo/edit?usp=sharing).  I've been asked to post a screenshot image of the GoogleSheet sample I'm working with, but, unfortunately, reputation is just shy of 10.

```
function submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var order1Row = 22, orderLastRow = orderSheet.getLastRow();
  var tplRowsNum = orderLastRow - order1Row + 1;
  var tplFCol = 1, tplLCol = 7;
  var tplColsNum = tplLCol - tplFCol + 1;
  var rangeData = orderSheet.getRange(22, 1, 2, 6).getValues();
  var colIndexes = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8];
  var fData = filterByIndexes(rangeData, colIndexes);
  var target = "POHistory";
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(target);
  var tgtRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var tgtRowsNum = fData.length - tgtRow + 1;
  var tgtCol = 1;
  var tgtColsNum = fData[0].length - 1 + 1;
  targetSheet.getRange(tgtRow, tgtCol, tgtRowsNum, tgtColsNum).setValues(fData);
}

function filterByIndexes(twoDArr, indexArr) {
  var fData = [];
  twoDArr = twoDArr.transpose();
  for(var i=0; i<indexArr.length; i++) {
    fData.push(twoDArr[indexArr[i]]);
  }
  return fData.transpose();
}

Array.prototype.transpose = function() {
  var a = this,
  w = a.length ? a.length : 0,
  h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;
  if (h === 0 || w === 0) {return [];}
  var i, j, t = [];
  for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    t[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
      t[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps Scripts: Transpose Array Error for "Undefined" Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135491/apps-scripts-transpose-array-error-for-undefined-field)

Comment: I am new to arrays and the transpose function.  I felt asking in a more concise way might lead to a more effective outcome.  Additionally, I needed to add two additional details into my request.

Comment: I would recommend removing the link to the spreadsheet (in favor of a screenshot of the layout for the input data area, including row/column references), and - since you state that this is to be a question about how to read a variable amount of data from that region, and not regarding the transpose - edit the rest of the question to better reflect its purpose. With the edit, you should include some code that you have tried, directly related to reading from that possibly variable-size range. There are some Sheet methods that may be useful (like `getLastRow()` and `getLastColumn()`)

Comment: tehhowch - thank you for the great suggestions.  having difficulty attaching the image, however.  Stack states users without ratings of 10 or above are not allowed to post images.  I, unfortuantely, am only at 9.  Wondering what you might suggest?

Comment: Start by reading [about debugging Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging), set a breakpoint before line 39, and then run / step through your code, watching the values of the variables. That error is saying that you are trying to dereference an array, but that the array is `undefined`. Find that, fix it, and then you'll be ready to move on to asking your question.